# JavaScript getting an elements class without any libraries

Tags: javascript, class

I would like to get the value of the **class** attribute for an element using JavaScript.  However in this particular situation I don't have the luxury of library such as YUI, jQuery, etc. and need to stick to the basics.

Specifically, I am looping over a table and want to check the class of the cell.

I tried:

`var colClass = el.getAttribute('class');`

and

```
var colClass = el.class;
```

But neither seems to be working.  In the above example, `el` is set from cells array of a table, such as `var el = document.getElementById('myTable').rows[y].cells[y];`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Maybe you should try this

```
var colClass = el.className
```

Answer (score 16):

This line that you posted should work:

```
var colClass = el.getAttribute('class');
```

Could you post what error you get in the browser? Make sure that el is not null.

If you won't get that one to work, [the attribute of the object is className, not class](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-95362176):

```
var colClass = el.className;
```

Comment: getAttribute('class') returns null.  For the same element, .className returned the class.

Comment: @Zugwalt - Its been a long time since the post. Do you know why getAttribute might fail ?

Comment: @HelloWorldNoMore Its possible this was seen in older browser like IE6 or IE7

Answer (score 4):

`className`?

[Element.className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className)

```
<html>
<body id="myid" class="mystyle">

<script>
var x=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
document.write("Body CSS class: " + x.className);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("An alternate way: ");
document.write(document.getElementById('myid').className);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember:

If you get an error and className does not work this can be due to your element being a jQuery object.

[image: works not on jquery]

In the picture above you see that I canot use className on a jQuery object