# jQuery get value of unknown element within table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

A table cell may contain an INPUT element, or a SELECT element, or some other element. I must get both the value and the class attributes from the element, in order to route code appropriately.

There will only be one element within the table cell (but the element type may change).

Problem: test1 and test2 are not returning desired values (classname and value for element in table cell).

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ykqaut4p/)

**HTML:**

```
<table id="tbl">
    <tr>
        <td class="pid">12345</td>
        <td class="tbl_vendor"><input class="vi" value="Ikea" /></td>
        <td>Stove</td>
        <td><input class="qty_in" value="1" /></td>
        <td class="del">del</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="pid">38674</td>
        <td class="tbl_vendor">
            <select class="vendSEL">
                <option value="1">C.P.O.</option>
                <option value="2">Knightin</option>
                <option value="3">CanDine</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td id="selTD"></td>
        <td><input class="qty_in" value="1" /></td>
        <td class="del">del</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery/javascript:**

```
var $this, qty, thisRowNdx, thisTR, vendorTD;
$(document).on('keyup', '.qty_in', function() {
  $this = $(this);
  qty = this.value;
  thisTR = $this.closest('tr')[0];

  vendorTD = $this.closest('tr').find('.tbl_vendor');
  var currVendorTagname = vendorTD.children()[0].tagName;
  var test1 = vendorTD.children()[0].getAttribute['class'];
  var test2 = vendorTD.children()[0].nodeValue;
  alert('currVendorTagname: ' + currVendorTagname);
  alert('test1: ' + test1);
  alert('test2: ' + test2);
});
```

Comment: What is all that jQuery/DOM meant to be doing? What isn't working? If I update the quantity what do you want to find? Because your solution may work, but it seems overly complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I was confused about what data I can get from a jQuery object, versus from the basic js element. As you can tell, I am much more comfortable with jQ than with js and was trying to fill-in some knowledge gaps. Think I've got (this part of) it figured out now.

Comment: Regardless, you still need to clarify your question; what is your code meant to do? In response to what? Where does it fail, what does it not do (that it should), what does it do (that it shouldn't)? The point is to make this question useful to others in future; if it's helpful only to you, and not understandable by others, then it's likely to be closed as 'unclear what you're asking.' Revise, and edit to improve; that way you have the opportunity to help others.

Comment: Hey, you're in Cambridge? You ever get to see John Lennox speak? Man, I totally envy you - would love to study math with that guy. I will update the question to address your points - much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all a matter of finding [the right reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-95362176). Or, this is even easier to read: [the Mozilla Developer Network page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className).

Thanks to answers given for this question: [JavaScript getting an elements class without any libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453799/javascript-getting-an-elements-class-without-any-libraries)

Solution:

```
var test1 = vendorTD.children()[0].className;
var test2 = vendorTD.children()[0].value;
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykqaut4p/1/)

---

Note that this should have worked, but didn't:

```
var test1 = vendorTD.children()[0].getAttribute['className'];
```

Comment: *`vendorTD.children()[0].getAttribute['className']`* will not, and should not, work: `className` is a property of the DOM node, not an attribute of the element, so try: `vendorTD.children()[0].className`