# How do I check other divs class property?

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I am trying to make simple JS slider of pictures.

By now I managed to add/remove class "active" on div elements that are stored in an array.

My problem is that whenever I add or remove class in specific div, which is selected, others stay the same until function comes around the same div.

I do not know how to check other divs classes whenever function "indexPlus" triggers. I am thinking something in the lines of for loop:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++) {
           //here should be the code that checks other "inactive (divs that have class
           //"picture active" but do not have the the same index as the selected
           // picture)" divs
        }
```

For now, my code is working correctly but not in a way I hoped it was going to. I was Googling for two days straight and tried to make this work. Maybe I am so caught up in the wrong direction and not thinking in a logical way, I am a complete noob at JS. Feel free to correct my code and/or make it more efficient. Excuse me for my English, it is not my first language. Thank you for your time and answers!

Here is my HTML code of the slider:

```
<div class="slider">
                    <div class="kontrola back">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="picture" id="0" style="background-image: urlsomeUrl)">
                    </div>
                    <div class="picture" id="1" style="background-image: url(someUrl)">
                    </div>
                    <div class="picture" id="2" style="background-image: url(someUrl)">
                    </div>
                    <div class="picture" id="3" style="background-image: url(someUrl)">
                    </div>
                    <div class="picture" id="4" style="background-image: url(someUrl)">
                    </div>
                    <div class="kontrola next">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And my JavaScript code:

```
var back = document.getElementsByClassName('back')[0];
var next = document.getElementsByClassName('next')[0];


var picturesArray = []; //creating array of pictures


//populating array by getting ids
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    picturesArray[i] = document.getElementById(i);
}

//setting the first picture
var index = 0;
var firstPicture = document.getElementById(index);
var class2 = firstPicture.className;
if(class2 == class2) {
    firstPicture.className += " active";
} else {
    firstPicture.className -= " active";
}

//function that executes on click of next button
function indexPlus() {

    if (index >= picturesArray.length - 1) { //this resets the index
        index = 0; //this resets the index
        var activePicture = document.getElementById(index);
        var class1 = activePicture.className;
            if(class1 == "picture active") { //this checks class of the active picture
                activePicture.classList.remove("active"); //this removes active class
            } else {
                activePicture.className += " active"; //this adds active class
            }
    } else {
        index++;
        var activePicture = document.getElementById(index);
        var class1 = activePicture.className;       
            if(class1 == "picture active") {
                activePicture.classList.remove("active");
            } else {
                activePicture.className += " active";
            }
    }

    //before mentioned possible for loop
    for (var i = 0; i < picturesArray.length; i++) {
        //code...
    }

}

//function that executes on click of back button
function indexMinus() { 

}

//event listeners
back.addEventListener('click', indexMinus);
next.addEventListener('click', indexPlus);
```

Comment: if your are using jQuery you can use .hasClass(),.addClass() and removClass() methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453799/javascript-getting-an-elements-class-without-any-libraries

Comment: @Prashanth Sorry, I cannot use jQuery. But thanks for answering.

Comment: can u create a fiddle?

Comment: @John Thank you for your answer! Although it did not solve my problem directly, it got me thinking in more advanced way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating another array called inactivePictures which included an array of pictures with everything other than active index.

```
function indexPlus() {
    //added code
    var inactivePictures = [];
    var notIndex = [0,1,2,3,4];
    var notIndex1 = notIndex.splice(index, 1);

    for (var i = 0; i < picturesArray.length; i++) {
    inactivePictures[i] = document.getElementById(notIndex1);
} 


    if (index >= picturesArray.length - 1) { //this resets the index
        index = 0; //this resets the index
        var activePicture = document.getElementById(index);
        var class1 = activePicture.className;
            if(class1 == "picture active") { //this checks class of the active picture
                activePicture.classList.remove("active"); //this removes active class
            } else {
                activePicture.className += " active"; //this adds active class
            }
    } else {
        index++;
        var activePicture = document.getElementById(index);
        var class1 = activePicture.className;       
            if(class1 == "picture active") {
                activePicture.classList.remove("active");
            } else {
                activePicture.className += " active";
            }
    }
    //added code
    for (var i = 0; i < picturesArray.length; i++) {
        if(activePicture.className == inactivePictures[i].className) {
            inactivePictures[i].classList.remove("active");
        } 
    }
}
```

My problem is now solved if anyone has any further suggestions, feel free to comment!