# Read the Div Class value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I read this `<div class="aigjdd">Mumbai, Maharashtra, India</div>` by using JavaScript

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript getting an elements class without any libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453799/javascript-getting-an-elements-class-without-any-libraries)

Comment: `document.querySelector("aigjdd").innerText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just select your data using javascript selector  then use it or show it as you want

```js
var data = document.getElementsByClassName('aigjdd')[0].innerHTML;
alert(data );
```

```html
<div class="aigjdd">Mumbai, Maharashtra, India</div>
```

Comment: My answer is not working?

Comment: You were missing `[0]`

Comment: @gurvinder372 which section?

Comment: After `getElementsByClassName`. Anyways, I see that you have corrected that now.

Comment: check my answer which updated 16 minutes ago

Answer (score 1):

You can use loop in javascript:

```
var data = document.getElementsByClassName("aigjdd");
for (var i = 0; i < priceEls.length; i++) {
  var FinalData = data[i].innerText;
  alert(FinalData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelector`, which will return only one `Element`

```
console.log(document.querySelector("aigjdd").innerText);
```